Firebase initialization and navigation issue in flutter
I'm developing a mobile application in flutter. My app is supposed to run only when I have an internet connection as it is using Firebase for its database.
I initialize Firebase in my main  function. However in a case when a user starts up without internet connection, I display a dialog, and when user connects to the internet, I initiate the same process and procedure of progress of navigation to next screen.
However the navigation happens smoothly in normal flow, but in the otherwise flow where user connects to internet after reaching splash. Navigation is not taking place, even though all function calls are being properly executed. I have checked with logging.
My current implementation of splash screen and its view model is as under. I have tried all logging but unable to workout. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong and what might need a fix?
Splash screen:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../View Models/Splash View Model.dart';
import 'Signup Screen.dart'; // Replace with actual path to signup screen

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final viewModel = Provider.of<SplashViewModel>(context, listen: false);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _initializeApp(context, viewModel ,false);
    });

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/drawables_png/splash_bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/drawables_png/splash_ic.png',
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  const Text(
                    'EASY FOOD JOURNAL',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Viga',
                      fontSize: 24,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  const Text(
                    'Effortless Tracking for Delicious Living!',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 40),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60.0, vertical: 30),
              child: Consumer<SplashViewModel>(
                builder: (context, viewModel, child) {
                  return LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: viewModel.progress,
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xff29ffffff),
                    valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _initializeApp(BuildContext context, SplashViewModel viewModel , bool callFirebase) async {
    print("finally here011");
    bool connected = await viewModel.checkInternetConnection();

    if (connected) {
      bool firebaseInitialized = await viewModel.initializeFirebase(callFirebase);
      if (firebaseInitialized) {
        print("finally here211");
        await viewModel.startProgress();
        print("finally here311");
        _navigateBasedOnLoginStatus(context, viewModel);
        print("finally here411");
      } else {
        _showNoConnectionDialog(context, viewModel);
      }
    } else {
      _showNoConnectionDialog(context, viewModel);
    }
  }

  void _showNoConnectionDialog(BuildContext context, SplashViewModel viewModel) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("No Internet Connection"),
          content: const Text("Please connect to the internet to continue."),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("Retry"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                _initializeApp(context, viewModel , true); // Retry the initialization
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _navigateBasedOnLoginStatus(BuildContext context, SplashViewModel viewModel) async {
    bool isLoggedIn = await viewModel.isUserLoggedIn();

    // Use addPostFrameCallback to ensure context is valid for navigation
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (isLoggedIn) {

        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SignupScreen()), // Change to home screen if logged in
        );
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SignupScreen()), // Change to signup screen if not logged in
        );
      }
    });
  }
}

View model:
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import '../Utils/SharedPrefs.dart';
class SplashViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  double _progress = 0.0;
  Timer? _timer;

  double get progress => _progress;

  /// Initializes Firebase separately to control when it is called.
  Future<bool> initializeFirebase( bool callFirebase) async {
    try {
      if(callFirebase){
        if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
          await Firebase.initializeApp();
        }

      }
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Firebase initialization failed: $e");
      return false;
    }
  }

  /// Starts the progress bar animation.
  Future<void> startProgress() async {
    _resetProgress();

    // Start progress bar animation
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), (timer) {
      if (_progress < 1.0) {
        _progress += 0.02; // Increment progress by 2%
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });

    // Complete progress after 2 seconds for animation consistency
    if (Firebase.apps.length != 0) {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
      _progress = 1.0;
      notifyListeners();
      _timer?.cancel();
    }
  }

  void _resetProgress() {
    _progress = 0.0;
    notifyListeners();
    _timer?.cancel();
  }

  Future<bool> checkInternetConnection() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }

  Future<bool> isUserLoggedIn() async {
    User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (currentUser == null) return false;

    bool onboardingComplete = await SharedPreferencesUtil.getValue<bool>('onboarding_complete', false);
    return onboardingComplete;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


There's a lot going on here, and I'm not sure I follow what the problem is. Instead of describing the problem in words, I recommend debugging it locally on your machine and telling us the results. So: put a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, then run the app in the debugger and check the value of each variable on each line. Now when you do this, what is the first line where a value isn't what you expect it to be?

it seems like The issue is with checkInternetConnection which is called only once, so the app doesn't react to connectivity changes.

checkInternetConnection is being called inside initializeapp() which is being called twice . once when widget builds and secondly when user clicks retry
